# Как с помощью JavaScript воспроизвести mp3?

Tags: jquery, javascript, mp3

Подскажите хороший, правильный и везде работающий способ, как с помощью JavaScript воспроизвести mp3-файл? Без показа какого-либо проигрывателя, просто жмешь на span или button и происходит воспроизведение файла.

Нужно решение на "чистом" JavaScript или jQuery.

Comment: [www.jplayer.org](http://www.jplayer.org/)

Answer (score 4):

Описаное выше решение не является кроссбраузерным, лучшее решение flash.
Зачем в этом коде грузить jquery лично мне непонятно...
тяжело было написать

```
var music = document.getElementById("music");
music.innerHTML = '<embed src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><noembed><bgsound="music.mp3"></noembed>';
```

Ну вот почему так много народа юзает jquery даже тогда когда оно нафиг ненужно?-.-

PS:кросбраузерного решения средствами JS - нет.

Comment: ну, на мой взгляд, в данном случае, попытку использовать jQuery-код можно оправдать, тем что он заменяет "нерекомендуемый" innerHTML. Но только в том случае, если jQuery и без этого уже используется на сайте.

Comment: Открываем исходники JQuery и видим, что функция html() == innerHTML ;)<br>. И если вам столь принципиально:<br>
var music = document.getElementById("music");<br>
var embed = document.createElement('embed');<br>
embed.src = "srcToMP3.mp3";<br>
embed.type = "audio/mp3";<br>
music.appendChild(embed);

Comment: ага, посмотрел исходники ... честно говоря, не думал, что jQuery использует innerHTML :( А как использовать appendChild() я знаю, спасибо :)

Comment: Да не заморачивайтесь вы, юзайте innerHTML наздоровье, поддерживается он нормально всеми, а нежелательно использование лишь потому что используя его мы уходим от обьектов и ООП(которое реально почти никто не юзает в JS'e xD) к, если так можно выразится, работе с документом разметки. Что не является желательным и тем не менее использовалось и будет использоватся всегда т.к. это банально удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть один способ он сочитает в себе javascript и jquery

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function play(){
    $('#music').html('<embed src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3"><noembed><bgsound="music.mp3"></noembed>')
    };
    </script>
<div id="music"></div><button onClick="play()"></button>
В `src` добавьте путь к аудиозаписи.
```

Comment: Я знаю что можно было и  без Jquery но почему то захотелось так написать..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".finish-button-middle-step" ).click(function() {
    $('.sound').html('<audio id="soundcard" src="card.mp3"></audio>');
    document.getElementById("soundcard").play();
    })
})
</script>
```

---

```
<div class="fir-trees"></div>
<a href="#" class="finish-button-middle-step">играть</a>
```