# Начать и остановить воспроизведение музыки по нажатию на ссылку

Tags: javascript, аудио

Как реализовать ссылку, при нажатии на которую начинает воспроизводиться аудиофайл, а при повторном нажатии воспроизведение останавливается?

Comment: `var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3'); $('.btn').click( audio.play );`

Comment: задавать один и тот же  вопрос не стоит... зачем надо было удалять тот вопрос, и пасать заново тоже самое...  ты что сделал?  в прошлом вопросе тебе объяснили, выложи пример, тебе помогут

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744775

Comment: @Igor я там не вижу ответов.

Comment: @ssh опубликуйте как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Air пример кода от автора в данном случае необязателен. Это хороший вопрос, про конкретную и специфическую задачу.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin ответов на вопрос больше чем достаточно и даже на этом ресурсе. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35072/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-javascript-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-mp3/35078#35078

Comment: @Telion отлично, тогда надо дубликатом отметить. :)

Comment: @Telion ну и по ссылке я вижу решение с jquery. Не факт, что автор этого вопроса хочет тащить jquery в свой код.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не против, вопрос интересный.  Но если бы он выложил код, хотя бы кусок, что он наработал... Было бы легче понять, что именно у него не получилось, что он может и как и чем ему помочь...

Comment: @Nick Volynkin я к тому что я считаю очень важным что бы автор вопроса всегда показывал свое стремление и попытки к самостоятельному решению вопроса. На этот же вопрос ответов просто бесконечность, а первая ссылка показывает отличные примеры http://bit.ly/2yCaxYj

Comment: @NickVolynkin, и еще  дополнение к пред идущему коммиту, он вопрос задает не в первый раз, когда вопрос был реализован за час буквально до этого  вопроса, ему написал,  мол, что именно у тя не получилось, выложи хотя бы код,  тебе помогут и в место какой-то реакции, он удаляет вопрос. Задает этот вопрос заново... И тут в комментах не вижу его участия...  Потому, что  что не вопрос...  А просто заказ...Кто то да сделает...  Мне не жалко, я могу ответит, и даже подробно и не только  я...

Comment: @Air, в данный момент, первая ссылка ведёт прямиком в этот вопрос. Ради этого собственно всё и делается: люди идут не от нас в Гугл, а из Гугл к нам.

Comment: @Air, JS знаю очень плохо , больше меня учили с jQuery работать , а тут сказали сделать на js все. Поэтому прошу помощи тут. Пытался разобраться сам, но знаний маловато.Но все же, спасибо!

Answer (score 6):

Воcпользуйтесь [Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

```
mySound = new Audio([URLString]);
```

Создает новый элемент mySound с типом Audio , c типом возрата: обьект, для которого задается ссылка на мелодию. При необходимости, задается также параметр codecs. Браузер начинает асинхронную закачку мелодии в кэш и воспроизведение оттуда.

```js
var radio = new Audio();
/*в место ссылки радио  ставь свой  audio.mp3*/
radio.src = "http://icecast.russkoeradio.cdnvideo.ru/rr.mp3";

document.querySelector('.radioPlay').onclick = function() {
  /* проверяем если музыка не на паузе воспроизводим*/
  if (radio.paused == true) {
    radio.play();
    document.querySelector('.radioPlay').innerHTML = 'pause';

  } else {
    radio.pause();
    document.querySelector('.radioPlay').innerHTML = 'play';
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioPlay">Play</div>
```

Comment: Правильно сказано, согласен! 

Comment: Можно ли сделать это не через id, а через класс элемента?

Comment: просто заменил id на class

Comment: И еще 1 вопрос, как можно отменить переход по ссылке и что бы место него воспроизводилась музыка по нажатию?

Comment: Dyxa,  ты объясни смысл, что именно ты хочешь...? Зачем тебе отменять переход?

Comment: Можно, href="" сделать пустым....

Comment: Смотри , мне дали элементы такого вида <a  href="ссылка на песню" class="класс элемента"><img src="картинка"></a> 
Мне нужно не меняя этих элементов сделать включение музыки по клику.

Comment: и что? ты озвуч полностью задачу...  ну я же не ясновидящий?

Comment: Не изменяя элементов в html сделать музыку по нажатию на этот элемент <a href="ссылка на песню" class="класс элемента"><img src="картинка"></a>

Comment: покажи одну ссылку на песню

Comment: newmusic/muzika_v_mashinu_-_angelika_vee_-_coco_jamboo_calippo_remix_edit.ogg

Comment: не вижу смысла использовать тег "а"...  это не грамотно...  что бы воспроизводить муз есть тег audio в html или объект new Audio js...  не правильно делать так как тебе надо

Comment: Я тоже так считаю, но сказали исключительно на js сделать и не менять тегов и тд, то можешь помочь?

Comment: ну макситум,  что можно сделать, убрать  href  и как в моем примере естественно в место div тег "а"...  больше я тебе ни чем не помогу

Comment: Ладно, спасибо хоть за это

Comment: @Air Спасибо, как всегда полезный пост (+)

Comment: @Alexandr_T, благодарю, предположу. что это не единственный за сегодня мне `+` от тебя)))

Answer (score 3):

`var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3'); $('.btn').click( audio.play );`